# How to Export feature_importances by using cross_valiation functions for RandomForest Model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, cross-validation

When using sklearn cross_validation strategy on the random_forest, how can I extract the feature_importances when 10-k-folder is adopted?

Based on my understanding, there should be 10 training session which will give 10 feature importance result if reasonable.

Comment: [cross_validate](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html) function have a `return_estimator` parameter, setting it to True will allow you to access the 10 trained RFs, and then you can simply access their feature_importances...let me know if u need further help

Comment: Wow, ok, let me have a try for that, thank you very much for reminding